# installing ros diamondback on ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot

Tags: ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have recently downloaded ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot and i'm currently trying to install ros diamondback. I have tried to install it using the 11.04 sources.list but it says some packages could not be installed and the final line in the terminal window reads:
"E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
Is there a way to successfully install diamondback on ubuntu 11.10?
Thanks,
James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11543/installing-ros-diamondback-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric-ocelot/) by [James](https://answers.ros.org/users/1218/james/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We will be bringing our Oneiric builds online now that it has been released.  There are a few patches which will be required.  Note, diamondback is not supported on oneiric as per [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) only Electric and later ROS distros will be supported.

If you'd like to run on Oneiric now, I suggest that you compile from source and submit any patches required for the upgrade.

The status of the debian builds can be viewed at http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-15**:
Oneiric debians are now available for most packages.  Oneiric is now listed at http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to [in earlier versions](http://answers.ros.org/question/618/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-1104), you can make packages meant for natty narwhal work on oneiric ocelot.

I successfully tried the following with electric, but it should also work with diamondback.

- Add the latest package source (in this case: Natty) to your sources.list ([electric](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu), [diamondback](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu)).
- Install freeglut3-dev, which replaced libglut3-dev in oneiric:

> sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev

- Install equivs, which will allow you to create pseudo-packages:

> sudo apt-get install equivs

- Create a file *libglut3-dev.conf* for the pseudo package linking libglut3-dev and freeglut3-dev:

> Section: misc
>
> Priority: optional
>
> Standards-Version: 3.6.2
>
> Package: libglut3-dev
>
> Depends: freeglut3-dev
>
> Description: temporary package to satisfy dependencies of Ubuntu 11.04 packages on 11.10

- Convert it to an actual package and install it:

> equivs-build libglut3-dev.conf
>
> sudo dpkg -i libglut3-dev_1.0_all.deb

- You should now be able to install the full ros desktop using one of the following

> sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
>
> sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full

- Now you still cannot use opencv and some other packages as they are linked against old versions of some libraries. Download and install the following packages taken from natty to get these to work anyway. Choose the correct link according to your architecture:

[libavcodec52](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libavcodec52)
[libavformat52](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libavformat52)
[libavutil50](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libavutil50)
[libavutil-extra-50](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libavutil-extra-50)
[libswscale0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libswscale0)
[libtinyxml2.5.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libtinyxml2.5.3)
[libvtk5.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libvtk5.4)

Afterwards, install all of these packages using

> sudo dpkg -i *.deb

wherever you downloaded them to.

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-10-28**:
Done, works, but still a problem with kinect (see post below).

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-10-27**:
Sorry, mean 11.10 (oneiric). I try to recompile openni_camera only, but it still fails because of libtinyxml. I think I could try to install libtinyxml.so.2.5.3, but I've not done yet.

**Comment by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) on 2011-10-27**:
Are you saying you are running Ubuntu 10.10? There are original packages for 10.10, no need for this workaround.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-10-27**:
I've followed all the steps, but I have problems running 'roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch'. This is the error (part): openni_node: error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml.so.2.5.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Ubuntu 10.10 comes with ver. 2.6.2